# Producing a mixture of release and snapshot builds from Maven

Tags: maven

I'm pretty new to Maven.

I guess I'm looking for a system whereby:

- Every time I push to SCM, my automated build tool deploys a snapshot artifact.
- Occasionally, triggered manually, the automated build too deploys a release artifact.

Currently, I have the first of those, but not the second. The POM says:

```
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

... and so Maven builds and deploys a snapshot.

The best suggestion I've had so far is to edit the POM to replace "SNAPSHOT" with "RELEASE", commit/push, wait for the build, then change it back, commit/push. Needless to say, I do *not* like that.

What's the right way to achieve this? Two POM files? (I don't like this either, since they will have a lot of duplication) Some kind of command line option that overrides `version`?

In case it matters, our build system is TeamCity, deploying to Artifactory. I'm hoping for a more general answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're pretty new to Maven, have you looked into the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) yet?

```
mvn release:prepare release:perform
```

it will uptick your versions, saving to SCM in the following order:

```
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
0.0.1
0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
```

and run `mvn deploy` on the 0.0.1 version to push it out to Artifactory.

Please be warned that this plugin is notoriously fragile/slow/buggy/aggravating/etc *under certain circumstances:*

- large number of small libraries
- many layers of dependencies between libraries
- libraries released on separate schedules (ie different version numbers)

these conditions are most common in large corporate environments.  Mind you, under such conditions, you'll still be able to use the release plugin.  The problem is that you'll have to call the plugin once per library.  That raises a separate question of how to coordinate making that many calls, calling them in the right order, managing version numbers, etc.  Even Jason van Zyl, the creator of Maven, has acknowledged that this scenario is a weak spot of the plugin.

On the other hand, a single call of the maven-release-plugin will work great for you if any of the following apply:

- you work alone or on a small team who all work on a single product
- you don't break your system into small libraries
- you do break it into small libraries, but they're all released at the same time

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. "notoriously fragile/slow/buggy/aggravating/etc" suggests to me that this isn't the "best practice" way of doing this. I want to understand whether it's just the wrong thing to want to do, and if so, what the right thing is.

Comment: maven-release-plugin is indeed the recommended way to do this, and FWIW it's always been stable for me. It looks like there's also a Maven/Team City/Artifactory integration plugin for releases: http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/TeamCity+Artifactory+Plugin+-+Release+Management

Comment: maven-release-plugin is my favoured plugin for building releases. I fully recommend the maven-release-plugin if you are building pure java-projects like jar, war or ear.

Comment: Slim, I should clarify. The maven-release-plugin is in fact the best existing tool out there for doing releases under the right circumstances: typically, a lone developer or small team working on a standalone product.  The "wrong circumstances" comes up most often in large companies with complex system consisting of numerous small libraries that are highly dependent on one another but released on separate schedules therefore the each have different version numbers.  Even Jason van Zyl, the creator of Maven, has acknowledged this weakness.  If this doesn't apply to you, then you're all good.

Comment: Accepted and gave the bounty, since the consensus seems to be that this is The Way. I have to admit I'm pretty mystified by the Release plugin's documentation -- I think it must be using a lot of nomenclature that I need to learn first.